# My sublime doesnt recognize @import. What should i do to import another css through sass?

Tags: sass

I tried several times to use @import 'reset' in my sass code. Unfortunately its not importing. The rest of the code sublime highlights and recognise with no problem. What should I do to @import the reset.css through sass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `@import`ing CSS files into your SASS, you need to specify file extension (e.g. `@import "reset.css";`). [See documentation.](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

**Note:** Importing file with `.css` extension will result in a real "CSS import" at runtime instead of inline SASS-like import. If you want to inject the contents of the file into your compiled CSS, change file extension to `.scss`.

Comment: How can I check if the reset css was really imported?

Comment: The `@import "reset.css";` should appear unchanged in your compiled CSS file. Check the _Network_ or _Sources_ tab in the developer tools (in your browser) to see if the file was properly imported on page load.